# Xamarin Forms Android app don't notify when sleeping

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I have a Xamarin Forms app and are using Azure Notification Hub. Everything works fine when the phone is awake, but when it is in sleep there is no notification sound or vibration. I get a notification if te app is killed and the screen is lit, but when turning off the device and wait a few minutes, nothing happens.

Also created an test-app where I followed a tutorial, but the behaviour is the same...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you try to test on another device, maybe there are some seeting on your device cause this issue.

Comment: I have tried three different devices

Comment: The notification does not work with the app closed only if the app is deployed in debug configuration, once it's deployed in release mode the notifications are correctly managed.